# In OpenSSL 1.1.x, determine if a given SSL* corresponds to a server or client side of the connection

Tags: openssl

The code I am trying to adapt from Openssl 1.0.x to OpenSSL 1.1.x is doing essentially the following:

```
if (((SSL *) pointer)->server) { /* do stuff */ }
```

`SSL` is a typedef of a struct internal in OpenSSL 1.1.x, visible from outside just as `struct ssl_st`, so direct member access obviously fails at compie time. Unfortunately there seems to be no `SSL_get_server()`, but maybe I'm missing something.

What would be the best way to implement the same functionality in OpenSSL 1.1.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "boolean" variable so it's "is" instead of "get"

[`int SSL_is_server(const SSL *ssl);`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_is_server.html)